# Rails Tutorial Rspec misunderstanding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

The listing 6.20 of Michael Hartl's rails tutorial shows the following code:

```
before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end
  .
  .
  .
  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
```

I am having trouble grasping this concept because @user.dup returns a representation of the exact same object, which is copied over to user_with_same email, but @user was never saved into the database anywhere in the file. Therefore, the user_with_same_email.save test should be valid every time. However, the test passes. Someone please explain this... is there an implicit database save on @user = User.new(...)? I know if it was User.create(...) there would be a save, but not for the new method. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not missing an implicit save.

`user_with_same_email` does save correctly (personally I would always use save! to be sure it was not failing silently)

What the spec is speccing is that the subject (ie `@user`) cannot be saved, because of the existance of a row in the database with the same email.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up... I wasn't thinking about it, but the code is @user.should_not be_valid. Is there documentation somewhere that tells me the spec tries to save @..user when I do a should_not call? I want to read up on that to better understand

Comment: ^ I was actually doing some more reading and I see that the valid? method, used by a block in be_valid tests whether @user passes rails' validation in the model file. Because I have the uniqueness validation in there, the model will check the database for uniqueness.

So there is no @..user.save, I understand now, thanks again!